# custom-set-faces only works with non-server emacs, but not /usr/bin/emacsclient and emacs server

Tags: emacs, client-server

I've been trying to work with emacs client/server functionality to avoid the long delays when starting a new emacs session. (emacs version 27.1 on Ubuntu MATE, BTW)

When I start emacs directly (i.e. no client server settings), the following code in my `.emacs.d/custom.el` file are correctly applied and I get a "dark-magenta" cursor. Yay!

However, when I use emacsclient to join a preexisting daemon, I have to reload `custom.el` within the session using `M-x load-file` for my cursor to change to "dark-magenta", which is becoming a PITA.

I'd really appreciate some help understanding this behavior and how to fix it.

## Background

### custom.el

I load `custom.el` at the end of my `init.el` file using the following code

```
.
.
.
;; loading custom.el at end of init.el
;; This ensures the themes are loaded before they are modified
;; Create custom.el file if it's missing, otherwise load it.
(defconst custom-file "~/.emacs.d/custom.el")
(unless (file-exists-p custom-file)
  (with-temp-file custom-file
    (insert ";; Autogenerated Emacs custom.el file")))
(load custom-file)

(provide 'init)

;;; init.el ends here
```

### Client/Server Scenario

#### Code that Starts Emacs

Here's the code I use with the emacs server/client scenario.  It checks to see if the appropriate server already exists, if not it creates it, if it does it joins it and starts a new one for future use.

```
#!/bin/bash
# Script for controlling whether emacs uses pre-existing daemon or creates new one
#
# IF you want to kill all Rmd-* servers, try
# pkill  -fe -9  "/usr/bin/emacs \-\-daemon=Rmd-*"


declare -a args="( $@ )"; ## need to use parentheses to prevent array of strings from being contatenated into one string

echo "Passed arguments: ${args[@]}"

# "$ids[@]}" returns space separated string
if [[ "${args[@]}" =~  .*\.("Rmd") ]]; then
    daemonCategory="Rmd"
else
    daemonCategory="nonR"
fi

## Get largest id # of --daemon=Rmd-[0-9]+
lastID=$(pgrep -a -f -u "$USER"  "/usr/bin/emacs \-\-daemon=$daemonCategory-[0-9]+" | sed -e 's/.*='"$daemonCategory"'-\([0-9]\+\)/\1/' | sort -rn | head -n 1)

echo "Daemon $daemonCategory detected lastID = $lastID"

## test to see if lastID is empty
if [ -z "$lastID" ]
then
    lastID=1
    echo "starting new daemon $daemonCategory-$lastID"
    ## Start new service
    /usr/bin/emacs --daemon="$daemonCategory-$lastID" 2>/dev/null
fi

## join already started service
## -c = create frame
## -s = socket-name
echo "Joining daemon $daemonCategory-$lastID"
/usr/bin/emacsclient -s "$daemonCategory-$lastID" -c "$@" &

nextID=$((lastID + 1))
## Start new service in anticipation of future needs
echo "starting new daemon $daemonCategory-$nextID"
/usr/bin/emacs --daemon="$daemonCategory-$nextID" 2>/dev/null
```

#### *Messages* Output

Here's what my *Messages* buffer looks like when I use the client/server set up

```
Loading /etc/emacs/site-start.d/00debian.el (source)...done
Loading /etc/emacs/site-start.d/50auctex.el (source)...
Loading /home/mikeg/.emacs.d/elpa/auctex-13.0.15/auctex.el (source)...done
Loading /usr/share/emacs/site-lisp/preview-latex.el (source)...done
Loading /etc/emacs/site-start.d/50auctex.el (source)...done
Loading /etc/emacs/site-start.d/50autoconf.el (source)...done
Loading /etc/emacs/site-start.d/50dictionaries-common.el (source)...
Loading debian-ispell...
Loading /var/cache/dictionaries-common/emacsen-ispell-default.el (source)...done
Loading debian-ispell...done
Loading /var/cache/dictionaries-common/emacsen-ispell-dicts.el (source)...done
Loading /etc/emacs/site-start.d/50dictionaries-common.el (source)...done
Loading /etc/emacs/site-start.d/50emacs-goodies-el.el (source)...
Package emacs-goodies-el removed but not purged.  Skipping setup.
Loading /etc/emacs/site-start.d/50emacs-goodies-el.el (source)...done
Loading /etc/emacs/site-start.d/50git-core.el (source)...
git removed but not purged, skipping setup
Loading /etc/emacs/site-start.d/50git-core.el (source)...done
Loading /etc/emacs/site-start.d/50tcsh.el (source)...done
Importing gnu-elpa.gpg-keyring...done
Loading /home/mikeg/.emacs.d/elpa/ess-20201004.1522/ess-tracebug.el (source)...done
[yas] Prepared just-in-time loading of snippets successfully.
Importing package-keyring.gpg...done
Contacting host: elpa.gnu.org:443
Contacting host: melpa.org:443
Contacting host: elpa.nongnu.org:443
Package refresh done
Loading /home/mikeg/.emacs.d/lisp/personal.el (source)...
Loading /home/mikeg/.emacs.d/lisp/no-x-settings.el (source)...done
Loading /home/mikeg/.emacs.d/lisp/ssh.el (source)...done
Loading /home/mikeg/.emacs.d/lisp/personal.el (source)...done
Loading /home/mikeg/.emacs.d/lisp/beamer.el (source)...done
Loading /home/mikeg/.emacs.d/lisp/modify-other-keys-extension.el (source)...done
Loading /home/mikeg/.emacs.d/lisp/jnm-term.el (source)...done
Loading /home/mikeg/.emacs.d/lisp/ess-init.el (source)...
[yas] Prepared just-in-time loading of snippets successfully.
Loading /home/mikeg/.emacs.d/lisp/ess-init.el (source)...done
Loading /home/mikeg/.emacs.d/lisp/my-tramp.el (source)...done
Loading /home/mikeg/.emacs.d/custom.el (source)...done
Turning on magit-auto-revert-mode...done
Starting Emacs daemon.
(New file)
When done with a buffer, type C-x #
```

If use `M-x load-file ".emacs.d/custom.el" the cursor turns magenta and the line

> Loading /home/mikeg/.emacs.d/custom.el (source)...done
> gets appended to *Messages*

### Emacs Stand Alone Scenario

In the stand alone scenario, e.g. `/usr/bin/emacs file.txt` everything works as intended, my cursor turns magenta, it just takes a while to get things started. In this case I get pretty much the same *Messages* buffer as in previous scenario.  Specifically, it looks like this

```
Loading /etc/emacs/site-start.d/00debian.el (source)...done
Loading /etc/emacs/site-start.d/50auctex.el (source)...
Loading /home/mikeg/.emacs.d/elpa/auctex-13.0.15/auctex.el (source)...done
Loading /usr/share/emacs/site-lisp/preview-latex.el (source)...done
Loading /etc/emacs/site-start.d/50auctex.el (source)...done
Loading /etc/emacs/site-start.d/50autoconf.el (source)...done
Loading /etc/emacs/site-start.d/50dictionaries-common.el (source)...
Loading debian-ispell...
Loading /var/cache/dictionaries-common/emacsen-ispell-default.el (source)...done
Loading debian-ispell...done
Loading /var/cache/dictionaries-common/emacsen-ispell-dicts.el (source)...done
Loading /etc/emacs/site-start.d/50dictionaries-common.el (source)...done
Loading /etc/emacs/site-start.d/50emacs-goodies-el.el (source)...
Package emacs-goodies-el removed but not purged.  Skipping setup.
Loading /etc/emacs/site-start.d/50emacs-goodies-el.el (source)...done
Loading /etc/emacs/site-start.d/50git-core.el (source)...
git removed but not purged, skipping setup
Loading /etc/emacs/site-start.d/50git-core.el (source)...done
Loading /etc/emacs/site-start.d/50tcsh.el (source)...done
Importing gnu-elpa.gpg-keyring...done
Loading /home/mikeg/.emacs.d/elpa/ess-20201004.1522/ess-tracebug.el (source)...done
[yas] Prepared just-in-time loading of snippets successfully.
Importing package-keyring.gpg...done
Contacting host: elpa.gnu.org:443
Contacting host: melpa.org:443
Contacting host: elpa.nongnu.org:443
Package refresh done
Loading /home/mikeg/.emacs.d/lisp/personal.el (source)...
Loading /home/mikeg/.emacs.d/lisp/no-x-settings.el (source)...done
Loading /home/mikeg/.emacs.d/lisp/ssh.el (source)...done
Loading /home/mikeg/.emacs.d/lisp/personal.el (source)...done
Loading /home/mikeg/.emacs.d/lisp/beamer.el (source)...done
Loading /home/mikeg/.emacs.d/lisp/modify-other-keys-extension.el (source)...done
Loading /home/mikeg/.emacs.d/lisp/jnm-term.el (source)...done
Loading /home/mikeg/.emacs.d/lisp/ess-init.el (source)...
[yas] Prepared just-in-time loading of snippets successfully.
Loading /home/mikeg/.emacs.d/lisp/ess-init.el (source)...done
Loading /home/mikeg/.emacs.d/lisp/my-tramp.el (source)...done
Loading /home/mikeg/.emacs.d/custom.el (source)...done
Turning on magit-auto-revert-mode...done
For information about GNU Emacs and the GNU system, type C-h C-a.
(New file)
Mark set
```

## Final Note

The problem persists even if I have a second `(load custom-file)` command in my `init.el file`. So it seems like I've got to have an active window for things to work.

Much obliged for any help provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this question is as same as the [question at Emacs StackExchange](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/77767/39388).

In short, customize your Emacs faces this (or similar) way:

```lisp
;;; UI-settings.el  -*- lexical-binding: t; -*-
;;
;; Load this file in your init file.

(letrec ((face-customizer
          (lambda ()
            (custom-set-faces  ; Put your original
             ...)              ; “(custom-set-faces ...)” here.
            (remove-hook 'server-after-make-frame-hook face-customizer))))
  (if (daemonp)
      (add-hook 'server-after-make-frame-hook face-customizer)
    (funcall face-customizer)))
```

---

I guess the problem you encountered has to do with the order of actions at Emacs startup:

> When Emacs is started up, it performs the following operations (see `normal-top-level` in `startup.el`):

> 10. If appropriate, it creates a graphical frame.
>     As part of creating the graphical frame, it initializes the window system specified by `initial-frame-alist` and `default-frame-alist` for the graphical frame, by calling the `window-system-initialization` function for that window system.
>     **This is *not done in* batch (noninteractive) or *daemon mode*.**
> 11. It initializes the initial frame’s faces, and sets up the menu bar and tool bar if needed.
>     If graphical frames are supported, it sets up the tool bar even if the current frame is not a graphical one, since a graphical frame may be created later on.

Comment: Thanks @shynur!  It's nice to know other folks struggle with the same problem and I wouldn't ever have found that solution if you didn't point me to it.

Comment: @mikemtnbikes: You're welcome  ||| Actually, this problem bothered me, too! I spent the whole afternoon trying to solve it several months ago. It has to do with the hidden initial frame (which is a little too esoteric to discuss here).